# Getting XML content within one element and spliting result by others subelements

Tags: php, xml

I work with xml file that looks like this:

```
<text>
  <paragraph/>
    First text
  <paragraph/>
    Second text
</text>
<text>
  <paragraph/>
    Third text
  <paragraph/>
    Fourth text
</text>
```

I need to get the value of text element but the result should be in 4 rows. So every `<paragraph/>` element starts new row:

1 | First text
2 | Second text
3 | Third text
4 | Fourth text

My code:

```
$filexml = File::get('../file.xml');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($filexml);

for ($i=1; $i < count($xml->text) + 1; $i++) {

    foreach ($xml->text as $text_item) {
        echo $i++." | ".$text_item."<br/>";
    }

}
```

My result:

1 | First text Second text
2 | Third text Fourth text

What should I do next? Or maybe there is different approach how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get that result using SimpleXML.  Maybe with XPath.  The problem is that your text isn't actually within the `paragraph` elements/nodes.  So the only way to access it is at the `text` node level, and at that level, you have the first and second, and then third and fourth texts together.  I've worked it to where you get 4 lines of output (with SimpleXML), but the first two and last two are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). In the expression you could get the text nodes using [text()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests).

Then you could loop those and check for empty strings.

```
$filexml = File::get('../file.xml');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($filexml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$i = 1;
$expression = "//text/text()";
foreach ($xpath->query($expression) as $text) {
    $result = trim($text->nodeValue);
    if ($result !== "") {
        echo sprintf("%d | %s<br>", $i++, $result);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/lPDP3)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
<text>
  <paragraph/>
    First text
  <paragraph/>
    Second text
</text>
<text>
  <paragraph/>
    Third text
  <paragraph/>
    Fourth text
</text>
```

for this:

```
<text>
  <paragraph/>
    First text
  <paragraph/>
</text>
<text>
  <paragraph/>
    Two text
  <paragraph/>
</text>
<text>
  <paragraph/>
    Three text
  <paragraph/>
</text>
<text>
  <paragraph/>
    Four text
  <paragraph/>
</text>
```

Comment: I have like 70 files with thousands of rows. I don't want to go this way...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this isn't particularly pretty, and I suggest you still give this a try using XPath, but here goes...

```
<?php

$filexml = "<root>
<text>
<paragraph/>
First text
<paragraph/>
Second text
</text>
<text>
<paragraph/>
Third text
<paragraph/>
Fourth text
</text>
</root>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($filexml);
$i=1;

foreach($xml->text as $textNode)
{
    $textCounter = 1;
    foreach ($textNode->paragraph as $text_item) {
        echo $i++." | ".trim(explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, (string)$textNode)[$textCounter++])."<br/>";
    }
}


?>
```

You were basically on the right track, but your inner loop needs to iterate over the `paragraph` nodes, not the `text` nodes again.  You also then need to be able to split apart the text within the `text` nodes.  If the file really does have everything on individual lines, then you're fine, as you can split on newlines.  If it doesn't (everything on one line), then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML does not work well with mixed child nodes. You will need to use DOM for that. You can use an Xpath expression to fetch the nodes (texts are nodes, too).

`//text/*|//text/text()[normalize-space(.) != ""]` filters for any child element node or any text node (this includes cdata sections) inside a `text` element. It will ignore text nodes that contain only whitespaces.

The result is a list of nodes that you can iterate with foreach. Check if it a separator (a `paragraph` element node). If yes, output the buffer otherwise add the text content of the node to the buffer.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$buffer = '';
$counter = 0;
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//text/*|//text/text()[normalize-space(.) != ""]') as $node) {
  if ($node instanceof DOMElement && $node->localName === 'paragraph') {
    if ($buffer !== '') {
      echo ++$counter, ' | ', trim($buffer), "\n";
      $buffer = '';
    }
  } else {
    $buffer .= $node->textContent;
  }
}
if ($buffer !== '') {
  echo ++$counter, ' | ', trim($buffer), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1 | First text
2 | Second text
3 | Third text
4 | Fourth text
```